# OldStyle numbers in text (everywhere)

Tags: fontspec, oldstylenums

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular}

\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle}}
0123456789\footnote{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

This produces an output with numbers in (4 or) 5 different environments.

1. The numbers that I type in the document body.
2. The page number.
3. The footnote-mark in footnote.
4. The footnote-mark in document.
5. The text in footnote.

Only the first one though, gets `OldStyle` numbers. I have two questions.

1. How to get `OldStyle` numbers globally?
2. Will that be typographically advisable?

Comment: Why don't you just do `\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{lmroman10-regular}`? This changes all numbers uniformly.

Comment: @campa You just beat me in seconds... :-D

Comment: @campa I am using a package which sets font already for me. I just wanted to `\add-` a few `-fontfeature`s, which is what I thought the command meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake lies in running `\addfontfeature{Numbers={OldStyle}}` only *after executing* `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. The `\addfontfeature` (alias: `\addfontfeatures`) command does *not* apply retroactively to all situations where arabic numerals are used.

You should either

- execute `\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}` immediately after `\usepackage{fontspec}` and *before executing* `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc., or
- add the option `Numbers=OldStyle` to each and every instance of `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. E.g.,

  ```
  \setmainfont{lmroman10-regular}[Numbers=OldStyle]
  ```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The `add` part in the name of the command is kinda misleading. Anyways, I will be careful. Lastly, do you think changing Arabic numerals to old style globally is typographically advisable (except math obviously)?

Comment: @Niranjan Most probably, in `Math`, normal lining characters only comes not `OsF`, but it's purely based on your wish

Comment: @Niranjan - A complicating factor is that oldstyle numerals generally have variable widths, whereas lining numerals generally have fixed widths; e.g., `1` is as wide as `8`. When displaying numbers in tables, it's highly advisable to use fixed-width rather than variable-width numerals.

Comment: Okay great! I will be careful.